# Interpreting results from OLS breakpoint test with dummy variables

Tags: regression, least-squares, econometrics, chow-test

I have estimated a regression and found a breakpoint using chow:

[image]

Then I created a dummy variable which is 0 before the break and 1 from the break until the end. This is the result:

[image]

I was assuming this p-value for the dummy variable means the break is not relevant. Is this correct?

I then interacted the variable with the other independent variables:

[image]

One of the interactions is very significant.

I don't know what to conclude from it. Is this break relevant and I should segment my regression or not?

If it makes any difference: These are financial returns of a company as dependent upon a stock index returns and usd exchange rates, all as log.